# CSS3 inner shadow disappear on scaling

Tags: css, scaletransform

i'm trying to scale a div with a inner shadow and an image inside. Here is the code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
       <head>
          <title> Home Page </title>  
          <style>

             div#b{
                box-shadow:0 0 10px 2px  #fff inset;
                border-radius:10px;
                width:230px;
                height:150px;
                transition: all 1s ease;
             }

             div#b:hover {
                position:relative;
                z-index:3;
                transform:scale(1.2,1.2) rotate(0.02deg);
             }

             div#b img{
                width:230px; 
                height:150px;
                border-radius:10px;
                position: relative;
                z-index:-2;
             }

          </style>
       </head>
       <body>

          <div id="b">
             <a href="#">
                <img src="img.jpg" alt="img" title="myimg">
             </a>
          </div>

       </body>
    </html>
```

The problem is that when hovering the mouse on the div, the image comes upon the div hiding the inner shadow.

I've already tried to z-index:3 the div:hover but no results.
May you help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Would you mind putting your issue into a jsfiddle? It'd help us help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px #fff inset;` and `display: inline-block;` to the `div#b a`

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j1v035bh/)**

```
div#b a {
    display: inline-block;
    box-shadow:0 0 10px 2px #fff inset;
}
div#b img {
    width:230px;
    height:150px;
    border-radius:10px;
    position: relative;
    z-index:-2;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: it works great, but if you have another image after that one, it appear a white border external to the image hovering the bottom image. Look at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uu9e41bw/) it would be easier to understand what i mean.

Comment: @backit add `vertical-align: middle;` to `div#b img` - http://jsfiddle.net/hoe6mvLe/

Comment: Ok solved, it was enought to set height:150px to a element ;)  Many thanks Mary for help